# Sitecore 404 page from item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

Getting Sitecore to respond with a 404 error code, [this blog](http://www.partechit.nl/en/blog/2012/11/return-404-status-code-when-itemnotfound-page-is-loaded) seems to be the most referenced, where a processor is added to the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline and the `StatusCode` is set to 404 while the response is written from the results of a separate request. Like so:

```cs
// Request the NotFound page
string domain = context.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.Host, UriFormat.Unescaped);
string content = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ExecuteWebPage(string.Concat(domain, url));

// Send the NotFound page content to the client with a 404 status code
context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
context.Response.Write(content);
```

This solution does not work well for me because cookies/security and IP detection is lost when it's the server makes a second request to get the 404 content.

After some back and forth with Sitecore's support, we came up with this code (just a quick sample):

```cs
public class MyHttpBeginRequestProcessor : Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (Sitecore.Context.Item != null
        || Sitecore.Context.Site == null
        || Sitecore.Context.Database == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
        Sitecore.Context.Item = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
        Sitecore.Context.Items["Set404"] = "true";
    }
}
public class MyHttpEndRequestProcessor : Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        if (Sitecore.Context.Items.Contains("Set404"))
        {
            args.Context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you put a new processor in the `httpRequestEnd` pipeline as well as the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline like so:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore database="SqlServer">
    <pipelines>
      <httpRequestBegin>
        <processor type="NewInstance3.Pipelines.MyHttpBeginRequestProcessor, NewInstance3" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel']"/>
      </httpRequestBegin>
      <httpRequestEnd>
        <processor type="NewInstance3.Pipelines.MyHttpEndRequestProcessor, NewInstance3"/>
      </httpRequestEnd>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This works perfectly on my local workstation (Win7 x64); however, when I copy the site to a Win2008 x64 server, the default IIS 404 error page is displayed. Setting the StatusCode to 404 on the `httpRequestEnd` pipeline is causing IIS to display its 404 error rather than the Sitecore Item that I set in the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline.

Sitecore support says OS shouldn't matter and it works for them on Win2008 server, but I have tried 4 separate Win2008 machines, I have tried a vanilla installation of Sitecore 7.2 rev. 141226 and every time, the default IIS 404 error is displayed.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your code:

```
context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
```